# Wordpress all php BUT index.php downloads instead of loads

Tags: php, troubleshooting

I've looked around a couple other solutions, but none have worked so far (modifying .htaccess, emptying .htaccess, disabling themes,plugins).

My website works fine, the index.php in the root directory works. Any other php file tries to download instead of loading. Not sure why this started happening. I haven't logged into the admin page in a few weeks, and now its not working. The server hasnt changed at all.

I am using firefox, but have tried other browsers, the same issue occurs.
All the permissions for all php files are still under www-data and rw-r--r--

What can I do to find/fix this problem?

Comment: You'll need to talk to your hosting provider.

Comment: This is self hosted, I am the only one to fix the problem.

Comment: No one can help? My site is broken without access to the login page

Comment: This isn't a programming question, as far as I can tell. It's a hosting issue. Something on your web server isn't working right if it's forcing all php files (except index.php) to download. If you're running the server yourself, you might have better luck asking on, say, [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).